# DTO objects are not passed in the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, dto

Here is my code on nestjs

dto file

```
export class RequestDTO {
  @IsString()
  name: string;

  book: {
    authorone: string;
    authortwo: string;
  };

  @IsString()
  title: string = 'Test Book!';
}
```

On post request, I'm passing all params but I'm getting only

```
{
name: "test",
title: "Test Book!"
}
```

Why is book object data getting removed from this?

Answer (score 0):

After updating to object dto

```
@IsOptional()
@IsObject({ each: true })
book: {
    authorone: string;
    authortwo: string;
};
```

its working fine